# Empty selects, multiple returns null and the single returns the first option

Tags: jquery, select

I have two selects, one "regular" and one multiple. If nothing is selected in the multiple one, then it returns "null", the single select returns the first option if I don't make a choice.

The thing is that I need the single select to return "null" if the first (empty) option is selected. Is this possible to define somehow, either via jQuery or something else.

Do you understand what I mean?

Cheers!

Edit:

---

The code is straight forward, just two selects:

```
<select id="single">
    <option>Make your selection</option>
    <option value="sel1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="sel2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="sel3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="sel4">Test 4</option>
</select>

<select id="multi" multiple="multiple">
    <option>Make your selection</option>
    <option value="mult1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="mult2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="mult3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="mult4">Test 4</option>
</select>
```

If you don't interact with the multiple select it will return "null". I would like the single one to return "null" if the user doesn't interact with it and the first option remains selected.

Comment: If you add code it might be easier to understand what you need

Comment: I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to browser behavior: first, in single select element the first item is selected by default.
Second, when the `value` attribute of the `<option>` tag is omitted, the browser will assign the text of the `<option>` as the value.

The most simple solution will be to add empty value to your first item in the list:

```
<option value="">Make your selection</option>
```

This way you don't need to make any changes in your JS code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry about the example, I know the browser will assign the text of the `<option>` as the value if there's no value. I'm just getting frustrated over here, hehe.

The thing is that if I set the option value to `=""` the back-end search engine interprets the two different. So I need the the single to return the same value as a non selected multiple select. I don't have access to the BE-code, unfortunately.

Comment: Using simple JS code you can make it that when the value is empty, the browser will not send anything at all by disabling the element. Is this feasible?

Comment: That did the trick. Removing the selects on submit if the value is empty. Thanks for the tip, @Shadow !

Comment: Cheers @Walker glad you did it yourself - removing is as good as disabling. :)